# how to verify the authenticity of a downloaded file from web using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, sha

Suppose I download a file from the web, say a Jenkins plugins hpi file.
How can I verify the authenticity of that file if it's downloaded correctly?
I am using the requests module to fetch the file.
below is the small snippet, where the URL is the link to the file being downloaded.

```
resp = requests.get(url,timeout=(2, 60))
file.write(resp.content)
```

Comment: See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/107814/downloaded-file-checksums

Comment: The word "authenticity" implies that you want to check the file against a separate MD5 hash or PK signature.

Comment: Unless you are *specifically* asking about how to solve a cross-version compatibility problem (in which case your question should obviously describe that problem) you should not mix the [tag:python-2.7] and [tag:python-3.x] tags. I simply removed the former.

Comment: Where would you get the correct SHA from? It's turtles all the way down unless you can vet it e.g. against a cryptographic signature. This obviously requires that the creator of the file provides a signed hash to check against in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, everyone for your suggestions. To give more clarity what I am looking at is ... I am downloading plugins from Jenkins's official site say "http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/2.222/latest/abap-ci.hpi" so I want to verify this after its downloaded that its correct and not corrupted .. So I wanted a way for that.